# More than one test fails due to import after jest is torn down - Supertest Typescript and Express API

Tags: express, jestjs, supertest

I am running into an issue where I am running multiple tests using `supertest` and `jest`. When there is only one test running then it works just fine but the second one throws the following error:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.
```

I tested this with two very simple tests:

```
describe("Default API", () => {
    describe("Default:", () => {
        it("should create a user in the DB", (done) => {
            request(app).get("/").expect(200, done);
        });
        it("should create a user in the DB", (done) => {
            request(app).get("/").expect(200, done);
        });
    });
});
```

They are the same but the second one throws the error. If I run only the first one there is no issue. This must be a setup issue Does anyone have advice. In my index.ts where I have the main express code I export app as follows:

`export default app;`

This is at the bottom of the index.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the simular problem and toggle down the issue, in my case I want to use mysql2 to access mariadb. That Module try to autodetect the charset and do to try to lacy loading that encoding.

But I have not found a solution for that for now.